# Correct word wrap in a span tag

Tags: html, css, validation

I've a form with an inline validation message in a span.

```
<span id="EndTimeErrors">
  <label for="EndTime" class="field-validation-error">
      Bitte geben Sie eine gültige Uhrzeit ein, zum Beispiel 8:00 oder 14:34
  </label>
</span>
```

[image: Ugly wrap with span]

Unfortunately the word wrap is really ugly.
I could put the validation message in a div, to beautify the message.
The result is better, but not perfect.

```
<div id="EndTimeErrors">
  <label for="EndTime" class="field-validation-error">
      Bitte geben Sie eine gültige Uhrzeit ein, zum Beispiel 8:00 oder 14:34
  </label>
</div>
```

[image: Using a div]

What I really want is something like this:

[image: Mockup of goal]

What CSS code would you use to achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

Comment: Thanks! That gave me the same result like using a div instead of the span. It looks better than the span, but not perfect.

Comment: Most elegant solution so far.

Comment: Great for having your content fly off the edge of the screen! Dont forget to use `display: block`

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code I ended up with:

```
<span id="EndTimeErrors" style="position: absolute; left: 300px;">
  <label for="EndTime" class="field-validation-error">
      Bitte geben Sie eine gültige Uhrzeit ein, zum Beispiel 8:00 oder 14:34
  </label>
</span>
```

I positioned the span absolutely and moved it 300px to the left.

This works, but I'm not totally satisfied with this solution, because the 300px are hard-coded. If the length of stuff in front of the validation message would change, I would also need to change the 300px.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely reason I can think of causing the difference between your `<div>` and `<span>` tags is that a `<div>` element is considered a block element, while a `<span>` element is considered inline.

Do you have some kind of wrapping element for the floated elements, something that looks like this?

```
<div class="row">
    <div style="float: left;">
        <span>Endzeit:</span>
    </div>
    <div style="float: left;">
        <input type="text" /> <span>10.2.2010</span>
    </div>
    <div id="EndTimeErrors">
        <label for="EndTime" class="field-validation-error">
                Bitte geben Sie eine gültige Uhrzeit ein, zum Beispiel 8:00 oder 14:34
         </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

If not, try it and I think it might work.

Comment: Using several divs and float them would work, but I want to avoid too many div boxes. 
I was hoping that there would be a css style that would enable me to use a span. The text should start at the same position at which the span begans in the first line and not just at the begining of the second line.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, all you need is a `<br/>`

```
Bitte geben Sie eine gültige Uhrzeit ein, <br/>zum Beispiel 8:00 oder 14:34
```

Comment: I added a br and in Firefox 3.57 the start of the two lines is still not aligned. 
The <br/> controls where the line breaks, but unfortunately it doesn't control where the new line begins.

Comment: I see. Posibly, put display:inline-block on the containing label.